# how to convert the %3A and %2F to : and / in the url in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

How to convert the replace(%3A and %2F ...) in the url.

**URL**
`https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https%3A%2F%2Furl%2F%26TIME%3DFri%2520Aug%252005%25202016%252011%3A40%3A14%2520GMT%2B0530%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29`

**Required URL**

`https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https://url/&TIME=Sat Aug 06 2016 11:42:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I was wondering is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote): "Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent."

Answer (score 14):

In `python 2.7`, use [urllib.unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote('https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https%3A%2F%2Furl%2F%26TIME%3DFri%2520Aug%252005%25202016%252011%3A40%3A14%2520GMT%2B0530%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29'))
'https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https://url/&TIME=Fri Aug 05 2016 11:40:14 GMT+0530(India Standard Time)'
```

In `python 3+`, use [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote(unquote("https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https%3A%2F%2Furl%2F%26TIME%3DFri%2520Aug%252005%25202016%252011%3A40%3A14%2520GMT%2B0530%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29"))
'https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https://url/&TIME=Fri Aug 05 2016 11:40:14 GMT+0530(India Standard Time)'
```

Comment: also using only once unquote does the job: 
'unquote("https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https%3A%2F%2Furl%2F%26TIME%3DFri%2520Aug%252005%25202016%252011%3A40%3A14%2520GMT%2B0530%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29")'

Answer (score 1):

For python3,

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote_plus("https://url/login_data.php?username=user&categoryid=0&URL=https%3A%2F%2Furl%2F%26TIME%3DFri%2520Aug%252005%25202016%252011%3A40%3A14%2520GMT%2B0530%28India%2520Standard%2520Time%29")
```